# How can I ignore a new line character when reading CSV file in VB.NET?

Tags: vb.net, csv, arraylist

I wrote a utility in VB.NET that reads an input CSV file, does some processing (specifically it ignores the first 5 lines of the input file and replaces them with a header row saved in another file) and writes the information from the input file into a new output CSV file.

Where my program fails is when the input data includes new line characters within one column value within the CSV.

I would like to ignore the new line character within a CSV data row when I load it into my string array.

Here is my code (its embedded in a form)

```vb
Private Sub Button2_Click(ByVal sender As System.Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click

    Dim incsvPath = strFileName
    Dim outcsvPath = fi.DirectoryName & "\" & outfilename
    Dim headerPath = fi.DirectoryName & "\ACTIVITY_HISTORY_HEADER.csv"


    Dim fileP As String = incsvPath
    Dim fileheader As String = headerPath
    Dim CSVheaderIn As New ArrayList
    Dim CSVlinesIn As New ArrayList
    Dim CSVout As New List(Of String)

    CSVheaderIn.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileheader))
    CSVlinesIn.AddRange(IO.File.ReadAllLines(fileP))

    messageTB.AppendText(vbCrLf & vbCrLf)

    For Each line As String In CSVheaderIn
        Dim nameANDnumber As String() = line.Split(",")
        messageTB.AppendText("csv file header row = " & line & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "csv file contents follow ..." & vbCrLf)
        CSVout.Add(line)
    Next

    Dim mySubAL As ArrayList = CSVlinesIn.GetRange(5, CSVlinesIn.Count - 5)

    For Each line As String In mySubAL 'CSVlinesIn
        messageTB.AppendText(line & vbCrLf)
        CSVout.Add(line)
    Next

    IO.File.WriteAllLines(outcsvPath, CSVout.ToArray)

End Sub
```

Comment: Use a `TextFieldParser` to read the data. The ability to read quoted fields contain line and field separators is built into it. If the line break is supposed to be within a field but that field is not within quotes then it's not a proper CSV file in the first place.

Comment: Also, unless you're using VB.NET 2003, you should not be using an `ArrayList` for anything. If you want a dynamic array then use the `List(Of T)` class. If it is supposed to store anything then use a `List(Of Object)` and if it's supposed to store `Strings` then use a `List(Of String)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is fairly hard work actually; it'll be easier to use a library that knows how to read and write CSV with newlines in the data than roll your own - not saying you couldn't, but it's a wheel that has already been invented so why do it again?

I used [Steve Hansen's Csv](https://github.com/stevehansen/csv/) - right click  your project in solution explorer, choose Manage Nuget Packages, click Browse, Search **csv**, install the right one

```vb
Imports System.Text
Imports Csv
Imports System.IO

Module Module1

    Sub Main(args As String())

        'open the headers file
        Using hIn = File.OpenText("C:\temp\h.csv")
            'setup instruction to the csv reader with headersabsent flag so we can get the first line as data
            Dim hOptions = New CsvOptions With {.HeaderMode = HeaderMode.HeaderAbsent}
            'take the first line into an array - these are our headers
            Dim headers = CsvReader.Read(hIn, hOptions)(0).Values

            'open the data file, 
            Using fIn = File.OpenText("C:\temp\a.csv")
                'setup instruction for the reader to skip 5 rows, treat first row as data, and allow newlines in quoted fields
                Dim fOptions = New CsvOptions With {.RowsToSkip = 5, .HeaderMode = HeaderMode.HeaderAbsent, .AllowNewLineInEnclosedFieldValues = True}

                Using fOut = File.CreateText("C:\temp\a_out.csv")
                    'convert the ICsvLine rows in the reader to rows of String() that the writer will accept, and write them under the headers
                    CsvWriter.Write(fOut, headers, CsvReader.Read(fIn, fOptions).Select(Function(line) line.Values))
                End Using
            End Using
        End Using

    End Sub

End Module
```

You don't have to use this lib to read the headers; you could just `file.ReadText().ReadLine().Split(","c)` it

If you want to perform per-line processing on the elements, do this:

```vb
    CsvWriter.Write(fOut, headers, CsvReader.Read(fIn, fOptions).Select(Function(line) ProcessLine(line.Values)))


    ...

    Function ProcessLine(input As String()) As String()

      'Note: If(input(8), "") returns input(8) unless it is nothing in which case "" is returned instead
      If If(input(8), "").Length > 10 Then input(8) = input(8).Remove(10) 'Trim if over 10
      If If(input(14), "").Length > 10 Then input(14) = input(14).Remove(10) 

      Return input 'Always return

    End Function
```

Comment: Thanks Caius Jard.  I am trying your suggestion, and it works great. I have two things I want to change from the input data to the output data.  I need to trim a string in one of the columns in the input file (take the first 10 characters of the ninth column).  I also need to wrap the values in the second column in double quotes in the output so excel does not read the values as a number and strip off the leading zeroes from what should be interpreted as a string.  In your example, how would I loop through the rows of the CSV input file and make the necessary changes before writing the result?

Comment: The looping is done internally by `CsvWriter.Write` on the `IEnumerable(Of ICsvLine)` returned by `CsvReader.Read`. Because `CsvWriter.Write` accepts only an `IEnumerable(Of string())` there is a small step of using LINQ to extract the ICsvLine's Values property which is the String Array of the values of the line. As such we can write a small helper function and pass the string array to it. Create a `Function ProcessLine(input as String()) As String()` in your code and do all your manipulating in it, and change my code so it says `.Select(Function(line) ProcessLine(line.Values))`

Comment: ProcessLine will be called once for each line of the file, you change the passed in string array and return it when you're done eg `input(8) = input(8).Remove(10) 'take the first 10 chars of the ninth column`. You said "i need to wrap the second column in double quotes to stop excel stripping the leading zeroes" but simply taking a number like 0000123 and making it "0000123" in your csv won't stop excel stripping the leading zeroes. If you your data with ', ie `input(1) = "'" & input(1)` then it will retain the zeroes but the apostrophes will show. If you then click in the cell and press enter

Comment: the apostrophe is hidden, the leading zeroes are maintained, excel knows the apostrophe is there but will remove it from the file if you press save. The only way I know of to get excel to behave "correctly" with minimal effort is to save the file with tabs as a separator, txt extension, fileopen it in excel (no double click), and go through the wizard, changing the relevant column type to Text on the final page. There is no way to save a csv, double click it in explorer and have it open in excel as a column of numbers with leading zeroes without some other data (apostrophe or newline) being

Comment: present also. As such, you need to make a decision: are you preparing this data for consumption by some external program eg driving a CNC machine, that will read the csv and correctly use it, in which case just write the data as is with leading zeroes- Csv library really will put the leading zeroes in,Excel hides them but prove with notepad they're there. Or are you writing this as a report for a human to easily consume by double click and open in excel, in which case don't use csv - use EPPlus library also from NuGet and create an XLSX file directly; it's as much effort and a better result

Comment: This works great, I can do the string manipulation on the first column I need to change in the called function ProcessLine().  I am having difficulty making edits to more than one column.  When I add a second character manipulation command, my helper function returns nothing.

Comment: Example helper function with one character manipulation:     Function ProcessLine(input As String()) As String()
        If Not IsNothing(input(8)) Then
            messageTB.AppendText(vbCrLf & input(8))
            input(8) = input(8).Remove(10) 'take the first 10 characters of the ninth column
            messageTB.AppendText(vbCrLf & input(8))
            ProcessLine = input
        End If
    End Function

Comment: Example helper function with tw character manipulation commands: Function ProcessLine(input As String()) As String()
        If Not IsNothing(input(8)) Then
            input(8) = input(8).Remove(10) 'take the first 10 characters of the ninth column
            ProcessLine = input
        End If
        If Not IsNothing(input(14)) Then
            input(14) = input(14).Remove(10) 'take the first 10 characters of the 14th column
            ProcessLine = input
        End If        
    End Function

Comment: When I run the utility with just one string manipulation command in the ProcessLine function, I get the result I am looking for: all rows are written to the output CSV file and the string manipulation is done correctly,  When I add the second command, the ProcessLine function does not seem to return anything.  The output CSV file only contains the header row.  I have tried moving the ProcessLine = input statement outside of my If Then statement and also nesting the second If Then statement inside the first with no success.

Comment: I guess I don't understand how to do more than one manipulation inside the ProcessLine function.  I appreciate any help you are willing to give!

Comment: I think the problem might be because you're using the "set function name equal to return value" way of returning a value, and you're hence overwriting the first change with the second. Also if any of the IF don't fire, then your function won't return anything. Just make your changes and use the Return keyword. Because formatting code in comments is particularly unpleasant I added an edit to the answer

Comment: Thanks again.  My function was not returning any values when the second If statement was added, as you mentioned.  The method you included in your answer worked well.  Again, I really appreciate your help.  I don't think I would have solved this problem on my own.

Comment: No probs! Don't forget to accept the answer by ticking the grey tick to turn it green, and upvote (by clicking the up arrow) it if you found it useful. Any number of answers (if your questions receive more than one) can be marked as useful, but only one can be accepted. Accepting an answer is important to do because it turns the question green on the dashboard so other people know it has an answer that worked out - people here try to answer questions with 0 answers first, then questions with no *accepted* answers (because maybe the answers posted were no good) so accepting helps guide them